# Format type of GPS data

Tags: gps

While getting GPS data from a receiver I get it in this format `4119.03283,7203.39095`. Does anybody know what kind of format that is? I just can't get my mind around what format this is like is it DMS, Decimal?

Comment: would you mind to post the aproximate coordinate where this location belongs, to? Or the name of next city. Is this lat/lon = 41 / 72 degrees? Usbekistan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is called `DM` (Degrees and decimal minutes).

4119.03283,7203.39095

is 41° and 19.03283 minutes  (the first two digits in latitude),
same for

7203.39095: 72° 3.39095'  (attention here: it should be 3 digits for longitude: so 07203.39095, check if you have 5 digits before comma, then the first 3 are degrees, else the first 2 are degrees. check further for missing leading zerors)

to convert to decimal degrees (format name `DEG`): 72 + 3.39095 / 60.0