# Converting GPS data

Tags: c#, gps, formatting

I've got a Chinese GPS tracker which I'm building a small app for it but I've been unable to properly convert the GPS data it gives me.
Right now I got from the GPS:

Lat: 3323.8602 S

Longitude: 07031.0972 W

[GPS Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393593/formate-type-of-gps-data) here they convert to degrees, minutes, second and apparently the format I have is called Degrees Decimal Minutes.
I need to format it to this type:

Lat: -33.43126

Longitude: -70.80126

Any ideas on how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

Take this: 3323.8602

This is 33 degrees, 23.8602 minutes.

Therefore, take your number, divide by 100, and take the floor. This will be the "Degrees" component.

Then, multiply that by 100, and subtract the result from the original number. This will be your minutes component.

Take your minutes component, divide by 60, add this to your degrees component, and you'll have a value represented strictly in degrees.

In the example of 3323.8602:

```
Floor(3323.8602 / 100) = 33 degrees
3323.8602 - (33*100) = 23.8602 minutes
33 + 23.8602 / 60 = 33.39767 degrees
```

I'm not sure where you got your answer of 33.43126